# Pass Table Value from View to Controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razorengine

Can I pass table td values to controller?

View strongly typed:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostClick", "Vendor", FormMethod.Post)) {
<table class="tblData">
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().SubmittedDate)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().StartDate)
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubmittedDate)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
```

Contoller code:

```
public void PostClick(FormCollection collection)
{
   /*Some Code */
}
```

How to pass table value from view to controller?

Have used JasonData & Ajax call and able to send the table data to controller.

Want to know any other method can be done because `FormCollection` data not able to find table values

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not create controls that post back. You need   to generate `input`, `textarea` or `select` elements - e.g. using `@Html.TextBoxFor()`. And the fact you are using `model.First().SubmittedDate` suggests you have a collection which means you need to generate each table row in a `for` loop. And you should be making use of MVC's model binding features by posting back your model (not using `FormCollection`)

Comment: thanks Stephen. Yes replaced FormCollection with EnityClass public void PostClick(List<Vendor> Vendor)
{

} . But List<Vendor> Vendor object is showing null. What can be replaced with DisplayFor() for the above Context to achieve result in Vendor list.

Comment: use ``Vender`` not ``List<Vendor>`` it is a single object not collection

Comment: Is your model in the view `@model List<Vendor>`? In which case you need `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){ @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].SubmittedDate) ..... }`

Comment: Thanks All for reply. Yes have used for loop . Data is displaying correctly at View . Have to Pass Table Value from View to Controller. that is actual Issue now ????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your need to generate controls that post back (`input`, `textarea` or `select`) and generate those controls in a `for` loop (or use a custom `EditorTemplate` for type `Vendor`)

View

```
@model List<Vendor>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <table class="tblData">
    <thead>
      ....
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
      {
        <tr>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].SubmittedDate)</td>
          <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].StartDate)</td>
        </tr>
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

Post method

```
public void PostClick(List<Vendor> model)
{
  /*Some Code */
}
```

Comment: @M.FawadSurosh, If you are having a problem, ask a new question with the relevant code (I cannot guess what mistakes you have made)